# why does realloc not seem to expand the memory. realloc not working as described

Tags: c, realloc

Okay, i have tried all solutions suggested but still no joy. The code I have so far is

`struct account* accounts = (struct account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));

```
while (1) {
    printf(" 1. New Account\n 2. Close Account\n 3. Access Account\n 4. quit\n");

    int choice = 0;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    int numberAccounts = 0;


    switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    accounts = realloc(accounts, sizeof(struct account) * (numberAccounts + 2));
                    newAccount(accounts , sizeof *accounts, numberAccounts);
                    numberAccounts++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("first name = %s\n", accounts[0].firstName);
                    printf("first name = %s\n", accounts[1].firstName);
                    break;
                case 4: exit(1);
            }

void newAccount(struct account *accounts , int size , int numberAccounts) {





    printf("please enter first name\n");
    scanf("%s", accounts[numberAccounts].firstName);

    printf("please enter last name\n");
    scanf("%s", accounts[numberAccounts].lastName);

    printf("please enter overdraft\n");
    scanf("%d", &accounts[numberAccounts].overdraft);

    accounts[numberAccounts].accountNumber = (100 + numberAccounts);

    accounts[numberAccounts].balance = 0.0;
```

}

It still spits out garbage for accounts[1].
However I did do a stripped down version, same code, but with less crap and that works fine. I dont understand it. its the same.

```
struct account{
char *firstName;
```

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

```
struct account* accounts = (struct account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));
accounts[0].firstName = "ben";
accounts = realloc(accounts, sizeof(struct account) * 2);
accounts[1].firstName = "tori";
printf("accounts[0] = %s\n", accounts[0].firstName);
printf("accounts[1] = %s\n", accounts[1].firstName);
```

The output from the first code is

first name = tori
first name = lication\debug

and the second

first name = ben
first name = tori
as it should be. inputs were ben first, tori second for 2 accounts.
weird

`

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post the text.

Comment: `sizeof  *accounts` results in the size of ONE account object.

Comment: `sizeof(*accounts)` is the size of one account. `sizeof(struct account)` is the size of one account,, so `realloc` is creating size of 2 accounts... is that what you want?

Comment: Soz, first time I've used this site

Comment: Your `sizeof` usage/logic is broken. it doesn't do what you think it does. you seem to be under the impression that `sizeof *accounts` will increase as you `realloc`, which is not true. And the first line of `newAccount` is broken from inception.

Comment: Yes,  just want to increase by one every time I create a new account

Comment: you're only increasing by 1 with the first call to `realloc`. The argument to `realloc` resolves to two accounts every time. To increase by one each time, you need to keep track of the number of accounts in a separate variable, then so something like `realloc(accounts, numAccounts++ * sizeof(*accounts));`

Comment: The int n is redundant, it was from a previous draft, forgot to erase

Comment: @BenRider The question isn't bad, but I suspect the down-votes are due to people not being able to copy paste the text in order to make suggestions. We don't want to type out all the code in an answer.

Comment: Yano will try that when I get to uni, ta

Answer (score 2):

As the others have pointed out in the comments, the sizeof(accounts *) will not increase as you allocate more ram. It is just returning the size of a pointer.

Personally, I'd keep track of the number of allocated accounts so that you can easily reallocate later - as such:

```
int accountsAllocated = 1;

//Initial allocation.
struct account* accounts = (struct account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));

accountsAllocated += 10; //If we we want to make room for 10 new accounts.

//Reallocate using the size of the pointer multiplied by the count of them.
accounts = (struct account*)realloc(accounts, sizeof(struct account) * accountsAllocated);
```

**This is a tweaked, working copy your code.**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct account {
    char firstName[256];
    char lastName[256];
    int overdraft;
    int accountNumber;
    double balance;
};

void newAccount(account* accounts, int numberAccounts);

int main()
{
    account* accounts = (account*)malloc(sizeof(struct account));
    int numberAccounts = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf(" 1. New Account\n 2. Close Account\n 3. Access Account\n 4. Quit\n");

        int choice = 0;
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            accounts = (account*)realloc(accounts, sizeof(struct account) * (numberAccounts + 1));
            newAccount(accounts, numberAccounts);
            numberAccounts++;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Not implemented...\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Which account position? (%d - %d)\n", 0, numberAccounts - 1);
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            if (choice >= 0 && choice < numberAccounts)
            {
                account* localAccount = &accounts[choice];

                printf("Acount = %d\n", localAccount->accountNumber);
                printf("First Name = %s\n", localAccount->firstName);
                printf("Last Name = %s\n", localAccount->lastName);
                printf("Balance = %.2f\n", localAccount->balance);
                printf("Overdraft = %d\n", localAccount->overdraft);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid account position!\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(1);
        default:
            printf("Invalid command!\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
}

void newAccount(struct account* accounts, int numberAccounts)
{
    //Create a local pointer, just so we don't have to reference the array position every time below.
    account *localAccount = &accounts[numberAccounts];

    //Zero out the memory used by the account.
    memset(localAccount, 0, sizeof(account));

    printf("please enter first name\n");
    scanf("%s", localAccount->firstName);

    printf("please enter last name\n");
    scanf("%s", localAccount->lastName);

    printf("please enter overdraft\n");
    scanf("%d", &localAccount->overdraft);

    localAccount->accountNumber = (100 + numberAccounts);

    localAccount->balance = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: also no need to cast the results of `malloc` and friends, although I get less heartburn from that than most folks on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Okay, couldnt wait tilltomorrow so i tried it now. replaced the previous with  accounts = (struct account*)realloc(accounts, sizeof(*accounts) * (numberAccounts + 2));   numberAccounts is initialised to zero. unfortunately, same result.  pulling my hair out haha

Comment: You have "sizeof(*accounts) * (numberAccounts + 2)" should be "sizeof(account) * (numberAccounts + 2)"

You want to allocate enough memory to store n number of acount objects, so take the sizeof(struct account) and multiply by the count you want to store. Instead, your comment example is allocating enough memory for n pointers.

Comment: tried your suggestions, still cant get it to work. I have updated my post to show the changes. I got it to work bare bones, but not with the function call main version. Appreciate all the help btw

Comment: @BenRider in your code, you are printing the firstName of the 1st and 2nd account after only setting the 1st accounts firstName. I think this is a mistake.

printf("first name = %s\n", accounts[0].firstName);
printf("first name = %s\n", accounts[1].firstName);

Comment: @BenRider I added a full working example that I've been playing with locally. :D